# Dynamic column generation in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have an object which has some 30 properties, depending on who is viewing the data, I need to  present just 10-12 properties to him.
These properties will form the columns of the WPF datagrid. I am using .Net 4.0
However, all this will happen at run time. I need to do this is the MVVM way.
Any direction as to how to achieve this will be appreciated.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

You have two options as far as I can see.

1) Expose a `ViewableDetailsType` enum property from your ViewModel that tell you what kind of view of the data you should show. In the view you can then create triggers in your `DataGrid` to set the `Columns` property of the grid to manually show the appropriate columns.

2) A better way would be to create wrapper, DTO type ViewModel objects for your underlying model object. One for each view of the object you want to expose. You then expose a collection of the appropriate wrapper objects to the view, and the DataGrid can use auto columns.

This is slightly more work, but it is truer to MVVM since the data hiding is taking place in the ViewModel, and can thus be tested.